# VBA split before & after the comma

Tags: vba

I have a report that produces the location as City, State... i.e. Baltimore, Maryland

I'm currently using the following to pull the full location string in:

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To n
Z = Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value
Cells(39, i) = Z
Next i
```

I know that I can write a formula for the field to do the work, but a VBA code would be much quicker.

excel formula for before the comma would be:
=LEFT(B39, FIND(",",B39)-1)

for after the comma (it's a state abbreviation):
=RIGHT(B39,2)

This does not work:

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To n
Z = Sheets(i).Range(left(("C6"), find(",","C6"))-1).Value
Cells(39, i) = Z
Next i
```

Any suggestion on how to incorporate the left function into this code?

Comment: What di you mean "*this does not work*"  What does it do?

Comment: That worked perfect... it yielded the city before the comma.  Do I manipulate the last integer to get to the characters after the comma?

Comment: Yes, yes I do.  Thanks!

Comment: Although Scott's answer would be the best way to solve your problem, as a FYI the correct way of getting the city/state using the approach you were attempting would be `citypart = Left(Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value, InStr(Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value, ",") - 1)` and `statepart = Mid(Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value, InStr(Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value, ",") + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Split:

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 2 To n
    Z = Split(Sheets(i).Range("C6").Value,",")(0) '(0) returns the first and (1) the second.
    Cells(39, i) = Z
Next i
```